# Currently on Windows XP-want to boot Ubuntu from USB

Tags: boot, usb, windows, windows-xp

I have downloaded the file from Ubuntu:

ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

I have placed this file onto an SD card plugged into a USB 2.0 port.

The instructions I have found from Ubuntu say, "configure computer to boot from USB."

Okay, so how does one do that on Windows XP. If at all possible I would like to do it without having to download another program.

Please tell me how to do this. Please be direct and avoid too much tech jargon. If I understood such terminology I wouldn't be here asking what is probably a very basic operation.

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

First create the bootable pendrive
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

After that insert the pendrive and restart ur pc ubuntu will start on its on
Or if dosent start then go to bios and select the option BOOT from pendrive.

Then try

U Can try these site for more information

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/installation